# Writing data classes with builder pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, serialization, builder-pattern

I have a data class which uses a builder to create the object and stores the data in a buffer in serialized form. I am planning to change the class to add and remove some fields. There are systems that will use both version of the class to create data i.e. the current version with all fields and newer version with removed/added fields. I am trying to see what is the best way to do this so that this is backward compatible(without breaking any consumer)?

I have couple of suggestions on how to do this but I am having a difficult time to pick one over the other.

Requirements:
The data stored has to be in binary.
Length of serialized record is same in both versions

Existing code

```
public class A implements Comparable<A>, Serializable {

private final Buffer buffer;
public static final Builder {
  private Header header//header with version
  private long creationTime;
  private SomeObject someObject;//this is removed in next version
  private OtherObject otherObject;//this is added in next version

  public Builder() { }

 //bunch of getters setters for fields

  public A build() {return new A(this);}

  private A(Builder b) {
   //build the object and put into the buffer
   validate()
  }
  private void validate() {//validates the object}

  public A(Buffer buf) {
   this.buffer=buf;
   validate();
  }
  public A(String encodedString) {
   this(ByteBuffer.wrap(encodedString));
  }
}
// consumers use this to get creationTime for object A
public long getCreationTime() {
 return buffer.getLong(OFFSET_CREATION_DATE);
}
}
```

**Solution1:** add new fields in the builder and use version in the header to decide which fields to use at build time (in build method) to create the object. Problem with this approach is that all the methods will exist at compile time to the consumers and unless they test their code every object will be valid. So it will be difficult to reason about which fields are required for which version at build time.

**Solution2:** Add a new builder in the class with the fields that you want. There will be duplicate fields that are in the existing builder.
Consumers can then use the builder that they want. This seems to be cleaner because builders will be completely independent. Problem with this approach is that since we are adding and removing fields, fields will be at different offsets so the getters will have to change to use an offset based on versionType. This is also problematic for future versions because then we will have this gigantic class with lots of builders and logic in getters for every version

**Solution3:** Create a new class (let's say B) that extends A and have its own builder. This way the code is more modular. Problem is that now there will need to be some logic somewhere to differentiate and know which constructor to call. For example , if a consumer is passing base64 to get an object A, it will need to figure out which version it is.

```
String encodedString = "someString form of A"
A a = new A(encodedString);
```

Is there a recommended way to code these data classes with builder patterns to make it both future and backwards compatible.

Answer (score 1):

**Aproach 2** combined with **aproach 1** + **correct binary representation** is the answere. Choosing correct format for your binary representation, the simplest thing would be to pick up json . Make concrete builders for V1 and V2 object and use the byte buffer to construct them. Each builder/Factory would be interested only in the fields it recognizes. You may consider using a version field if a builder/factory attempts to deserialize wrong version exception may be thrown. The concrete builder/factory will be build only objects of the version it recognizes.

Subclassing is unnessessary in my opinion. You can separate the Builder/factory class from the object class. See "StreamSerializer" from Hazelcast as an example, completly external class to the entity dedicated only to doing marshaling.

Using proper format will **fix your problem with offset** from Aproach two.  If you must have it in binary form then a workaround would be to use flat format where record size is bigger than nessesary and you have reserved free space for changes. In the old Cobol days this is how they were doing it. I don't recommend you to do that though. Use json :) it is simplest may be not most effecient. You can also check https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/ protocol buffers.

Depending on what layout you choose for serialization when demarshaling you may configure chain of responsibility that attempts to deserialize a stream portion. When you deprecate a version, the marshaler will be just removed/deactivated from the chain.

Comment: one detail I forgot to mention was that the size of the record (in binary) has to be same for both versions for some weird regions(for backward compatibiltiy). That's what making this a little difficult to fix the problem with approach two. On using json, that's going to be a little difficult because binary form was chosen because of memory reasons (when accessing different fields and things related to GC).     

I do like approach 2 more than 1, I will look into the layout option to see if we can configure the chain of responsibility in some way.

Comment: @jigsaw the argument for garbadge collection and memory is not serious in 99% of the applications. I seriously doubt you are doing the next real time trading platform that this will be an argument.

Comment: Anyway if you are going for the Binary. You don't need to read the complete record in order to figure out the version. Divide the record into two parts first part is header containing metadata, second part is dynamic depending on the type of object. I think you are not giving all the requirements so It is difficult for me to say anything more than that. But you should not use custom binary format, use protobufferer instead.

Comment: Yes, I can read the header first to figure out the version of the object but that does not change the fact that the getter will have to return the fields based on which version it is by changing the offsets based on version and I was trying to avoid that. Does that makes sense or am I missing something in what you are saying?  

For example:  

`public getCreationTime() {  
  if (version == 0) {  
   return buffer.get(offset1);  
 } else {  
  return buffer.get(offset2);  
}  
}  
`